# c++ Opencv 3.0 SVM Prediction error

Tags: c++, svm, opencv3.0, predict

```
for (map<string,Ptr<SVM>>::iterator it = classifiers.begin(); it != classifiers.end(); ++it) {
                float res = (*it).second->predict(hist);  ///****error 
                if ((*it).first == "misc" && res > 0.9) {
                    continue;
                }
                if(res > 1.0) continue;
                if (res < minf) {
                    minf = res;
                    minclass = (*it).first;
                }
            }
```

the error was found at `predict(hist)` : Opencv error : Assertion failed (samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == CV_32F) in predict.

Im not sure what going wrong with the error here and i did read from the Opencv 3.0 Doc where the predict require 3 parameters and some internet sample code was just simple as 1 parameter.

Is anyone have facing the same error before?

Comment: You can call  `predict` with 1 argument, and that's fine. Here either 1) `hist` number of columns is not the same as your training data, or 2) `hist` is not of type `CV_32F`. I'd go with 2), since probably you made your `hist` of some integer type. Just use `convertTo(..., CV_32F);`

Comment: HI MIki, thanks for the prompt reply. Yes, i also had did that when i define Mat hist; hist.convertTo(hist, CV_32F). Now even, i had try to do convert again before to make sure hist is CV_32F. But unfortunately, the error still the same. So i wonder how i should try your first solutions? how do i know the number of column in train data and hist? Thanks very appreciated your reply,

Comment: `svm->getVarCount()` should be equal to `hist.cols`

Comment: HI Miki. Im experiencing BOW and SVM classifier.  I had created a training_sample file at 49 rows and 1000 cols, vocabulary is 1000 rows and 64 cols and last SVM classifier to load into my program. As told, my return of hist is 1 rows and 1000 cols. So i still getting same error now.

Comment: anyway im using hist.cols and hist.rows to return numbers of cols rows.

Comment: So you trained your SVM using a 49x1000 mat (ok), or you trained it on your 1000x64 mat (not ok)?

Comment: I train my svm in 49x1000 and my hist 1x1000, the predict(hist) is not working as the same error shown.

Comment: Can you post _all_ relevant code? it seems everything ok right now, probably just some silly mistake.

Comment: sure, possible maybe via email?

Comment: no... edit the relevant part into the question

Comment: Mat img,response_hist; response_hist.convertTo(response_hist, CV_32F);
        ..
        vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
        detector->detect(img,keypoints);
        bowDE.compute(img, keypoints, response_hist); //, &pointIdxsOfClusters);
        if (response_hist.cols == 0 || response_hist.rows == 0) {
            continue;
        }

Comment: I think i can't make it here since it has limited text i can do here.

Comment: There is an _edit_ link in your question (under the tags). Add the code into your question

Comment: Thanks miki..i had updated the code above.

Comment: 1) I don't see where you're using `hist`. It will always be a 0x0 matrix. 2) a lot of bad practice stuff here... but that's not the point here

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. This is the first time I'm experiencing Bag of Word. I will do it properly hopefully can get a properly guideline for this coding. Appreciated for your advise.